# Overriding ToString and `%A` specifier

Tags: f#, printf, nullreferenceexception

If a override `ToString` in a type

```
type TestMe ()=
    override __.ToString() = null
```

and then I output it through the `"%A"` specifier

```
printfn "*%A*" (TestMe())
```

why does it throw a `System.NullReferenceException`?

I would have expected it to behave like

```
printfn "*%A*" null
```

which simply prints `<null>` without any exceptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue [got fixed in F# 4.1](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/commit/7ae2aca94b83368b79eb1677c4e9ee3a996f1af4), which now explicitly handles the case where `ToString()` returns `null`. Before that fix, the `null` would travel up the stack and eventually be dereferenced.

Upgrading your FSharp.Core version will fix the issue for you.

Having said that, I'd like to point out that returning `null` from `ToString` is a generally a big no-no. Even [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) have a specific warning about it.

Comment: Do you mean got fixed in F# 4.1? Since I have F# 4.0 in VS2015 with net462. And of course it was only the mcve, the actual code is [this](https://gist.github.com/giuliohome/104185116b28273403cb2b6ba6cec210#file-gistfile1-txt-L1-L23), where I was testing a corner case: `printfn "*%A*" (TrimNonEmptyString (null))`. I will update to VS2017 later, but I assume it will fix the issue, thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, `Install-Package FSharp.Core` did the trick! From the console I can read "Successfully installed `FSharp.Core 4.2.1`". Also the previous version `FSharp.Core.4.1.17` - which is in [expecto](https://github.com/haf/expecto/issues/188#issuecomment-317245993) dependencies - is enough to solve the problem.

Comment: You're right, I meant 4.1. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure?

I get the following output:

```
type TestMe ()=
    override __.ToString() = null

TestMe()
//val it : TestMe =

printfn "%A" (TestMe())
//val it : unit = ()
```

There is a slight difference as I assume reflection is doing some translation between `unit` and `null` but it doesn't show an exception. Why do you need the stars in `"*%A*"`?

Comment: You just have a newer version of F#. Stars around `%A` are a common way to distinguish between outputting an empty string and not outputting anything at all.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin, ah, thanks, * trick is nice. I suspected maybe an older version but was too lazy to start VS2015. This is indeed in F# 4.1.